# When did the Borg contact the Cardassians?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

In an answer [to this recent](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54309/why-are-there-so-many-human-borg) question there is a screenshot of a Cardassian who has been assimilated by the Borg. My question is simple: when the hell did the Borg come into contact with the Cardassians? According to every *Star Trek* map I have encountered, the Cardassian Union is on the opposite side of the Federation to Borg space, which would seem to preclude the Borg 'recruiting' while passing through on their way to assimilate Earth.

Is there any canon or non-canon material on how exactly the Borg came into contact with Cardassians?

Comment: A map of earth shows that Australia is on the opposite side of the Middle East to the UK, yet you do occasionally find antipodeans who have made it over here without our chums in Dubai being any the wiser.

Comment: The Borg transwarp corridors seem to be one way unless a base is established on the far side to allow a return trip. Without making a transwarp voyage, the idea that a Borg cube could travel around Federation space, either through or around Breen and Ferengi space, stop off in Cardassian territory, then spin around and travel back towards the Delta Quadrant, then speed towards Earth, all without the Federation noticing its actions until it directly approaches their borders, is ludicrous. Also, comparing space travel to a trip on a single planet displays "two-dimensional thinking," Khan.

Comment: sure, but the idea that Cardassians are only found in Cardassian space, and Borg in Borg space, is equally ridiculous.

Comment: Of course, but they are certainly more likely to run into each other if they're in each other's backyards.

Answer (score 11):

The Hansens were exploring the Delta Quandrant, investigating the Borg, long before *Q Who*. No reason to think that there might not have been some Cardassians out exploring the galaxy too.

Comment: [Even some Ferengi made it to the other side of Borg space...](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/False_Profits_(episode))

Comment: The Ferengi had a wormhole to do it though. I even believe the Ferengi in question may have arrived there during a *TNG* episode, featuring the unstable Barzan wormhole. I doubt the Cardassians got there the same way.

Comment: “when First Contact takes place relations between Cardassia and the Federation are fairly amicable” — I don’t think that’s right. According to Memory Alpha, [First Contact takes place on stardate 50893.5](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact), whilst [the Cardassians joined the Dominion, with whom the Federation were at war, around stardate 50564.2](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/By_Inferno's_Light_(episode)).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite My mistake for not double checking the actual star dates. I had simply used the air/release dates to compare relative dates. I've removed that paragraph.

Comment: @JamesSheridan It's definitely the same Ferengi and the Barzan wormhole, this end still bouncing around.  My point was more along the lines of, you can't rely on all members of a species sticking near their homeworld.  Especially with accidents included

Answer (score 0):

The Borg have transwarp hubs in all quadrants of the galaxy. It's likely that they've encountered, and assimilated limited samples of, many ships from many species in areas where they're not necessarily in the process of invading.

Or, there a Cardassian could have been a passenger on some other ship that was assimilated, such as a transport vessel.

Comment: This answer is as speculative as the previous one.

Comment: Not denying that. didn't deserve a downvote though.

Comment: I didn't downvote you.