# Has a Klingon ever been head-butted to any effect by a non-Klingon?

Tags: star-trek, klingon

Given the tough cranial ridge that nature has selected to incorporate into the Klingon forehead, has any non-Klingon given a Klingon an effective headbutt (on their head) on-screen?

Comment: Do you mean in the head? A headbutt does not necessarily mean an attack with one's head to another's head. It only requires the attacker's head to be involved - the target can be any body part.

Comment: Yes. I updated question

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKQDRxs5Nzk Data does not give the headbutt, but the klingon is the only one hurt in this scene. Not sure if this counts as answer...

Comment: @kl78 - Totally forgot about that one.

Comment: @jl78 -  You should post that as an answer

Comment: I believe in the real-world, actual headbutts target the (much softer) bridge of the opponent’s nose in order to be effective — otherwise it’s like punching someone right on their clenched fist. Unfortunately, it looks like [Klingons have a ridge there too](http://cdn-static.denofgeek.com/sites/denofgeek/files/1/59//worf_0.jpg) — although I don’t think we ever get confirmation that their head or nose ridges are actually tough.

Comment: This question reminds me of Krogan culture in Mass Effect.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Although technically Data is not *giving* the headbutt but receiving it, only the Klingon Captain Nu'Daq was hurt in the episode [TNG: The Chase](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Chase_%28episode%29).

Comment: Data is most definitely a humanoid. Humanoid is defined as *(especially in science fiction) a being resembling a human in its shape.* And he resembles humans in [more than just appearance](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Measure_Of_A_Man_(episode)).

Comment: @corsika: Sure,but "not an biological alien being with a body plan that is generally like that of a human" sounds to complicated and I found no other short word which describes this. (No native english speaker) I just wanted to state that Data is not part of the typical "main" alien races like the others around Star Trek and therefore is maybe not the best example as answer. Feel free to edit my answer with a better matching phrase...

Comment: @corsiKa Starfleet has a convoluted definition of humanoid: [Are Borg Drones humanoid?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/121529)

Comment: @armadillo doesn't seem convoluted to me. Seems quite consistent actually.

Comment: Is this the only example?

Comment: Words can have different meanings: that is totally unsurprising.  "humanoid" can mean literally "the shape of a human".  so, a peice of plastic, that happens to be the shape of a human, is humanoid.  In game engineering, you use "humanoid" constantly to mean, simply, anything at all with "two leg-like protrusions and two arm-like protrusions".  however, "humanoid" can of course mean "biological being" - as opposed to a robot.  it's perfectly normal that the meaning of some words depends on context.

Comment: The only quality in the definition of "humanoid" that you mention is that Data is not biological. If you want to emphasize that fact, why not just say he is not an organic being? Or alternatively, that he is a machine or perhaps even that he is "artificial." All of those descriptions would be accurate and would probably convey what you wanted to.

Comment: Since Borg drones shown in the series are almost exclusively assimilated from humanoid creatures, are you implying that adding some cybernetic implants and a hivemind to a human being makes that creature a non-humanoid? I agree with corsiKa. Totally consistent.

Comment: Also, @iMerchant, I can't find any reference online, but I have watched TNG, DS9 and Voyager by air date in a loop when I am home pretty much constantly over the last few years. I *believe* there is an instance of what you're looking for when Jadzia Dax headbutts a Klingon in DS9, but I can't remember the episode or the scene. I think it may be the episode when they find the Sword of Kahless and are being chased through the caverns.

Comment: @L0j1k - That'd be great if someone could find & note which episode that was. Also, not sure how the whole humanoid thing came up; I just said non-Klingon. If Species 8472 head butted a Klingon, I'd take it.

Comment: That's my boy! ;)

Comment: @iMerchant So pretty much I'll be thinking of this question while I watch the show. I make it through all three and start the loop over again about once every two or three months, depending. I am in the last season of DS9 and halfway through Voyager (by air date). I'll try to remember to re-watch the episode I'm thinking about, otherwise I'll probably be able to provide you a complete answer in the next couple of months. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Given the construction of the Klingon head, most species would suffer more harm than they inflict from head butting a Klingon.

There is only one fragile Human who ever accidentally harmed - in a sense - a Klingon with an (accidental) head butt.

DS9 "Let He Who is Without Sin":

> WORF: When I was thirteen, I was captain of my school soccer team. We had made the championships, and I was determined to win. Near the end of the second half, with the score tied, my team got a corner kick. The ball sailed up high. Both I and one of my opponents, a human boy named Mikel, leaped up to head the ball. He had position, but I was determined to score. I remember laughing with excitement as I threw myself at him.
>   DAX: Go on.
>   WORF: The next thing I knew, the ball was sailing into their goal. I roared with triumph and turned around to Mikel to gloat, only to find him lying on the grass bleeding. Our heads had collided when we both went up for the ball. I had not feel the impact, but I had broken his neck, and he died the next day.
>   DAX: It was an accident.
>   WORF: Which only makes it worse. Compared to Klingons, humans are fragile creatures. I realised at that moment to live among them I must practice restraint.
>   DAX: That must have been difficult for you.
>   WORF: At first. In time it became part of who I was, who I am.

Since the only way for a fragile Human to hurt a Klingon with a head butt is to make him feel sorry for hurting the Human, and since Worf was probably the one Klingon most likely to feel sorry for hurting people, Mikel was probably the only Human to ever hurt a Klingon with a head butt.

Answer (score 3):

Sisko actually delivers a head butt in DS9: Apocalypse Rising around 27:29, when the DS9 boys attend the Order of the Bat'leth ceremony.  There's an establishing shot showing Sisko and a Klingon in a one-handed tugging stance.  Then cut to a conversation about blood wine and how it's good the anti-intoxicant is still working "or you would be so drunk you would not be able to stand."

Then cut back to the fight, and Sisko pretty clearly head butts the Klingon before throwing his opponent to the ground.  There's a thud sound, Sisko's hair flies in the air, and they're still in the one-handed grip (so not a strike).